# specifying erb template file encoding

Tags: ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, ruby-2.1

I try to run a rails app (Airesis), using apache2 and passenger. The erb files contain UTF-8 encoded characters. I see

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8):
```

errors, corresponding to lines in the erb containing utf-8 encoded characters.
Interestingly another machine with the exact same setup up from rvm does not have this issue. The only difference we could identify that the working machine had hu_HU.UTF-8 as the default locale, as the non-working had C. But the problem did not go away after changing the system locale.

Tried to specify

```
<% # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- %>
```

In the beginning of the erb file, checked that the Application class have

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

added

```
Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"
```

to the beginning of config/application.rb, added

```
export RUBYOPT=-Ku
```

to /etc/default/apache2, and

```
SetEnv RUBYOPT=-Ku
```

to the apache config file.

None of them solved the problem.

I use apache2, and all ruby related things, including passenger installed using rvm by root.
Versions:
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.0.2
passenger 4.0.56

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using non ASCII characters in /config/application.yml can couse this error.